# Suma de dos inputs con React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy empezando a manejar states con React Hooks y me gustaría lograr la suma de dos inputs a traves de un botón.
Hasta ahora manejo el onChange de los inputs , pero no se como sumar esos estados.
Este es mi código:

```
import React from 'react';


export default function Suma (){
    //hook defined
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
        num1: "",
        num2: "",
    });

    //handle input change 

    const handleInput = function(e){
        setInput({
            ...input, 
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    //suma function

    const suma = function(){
     
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={handleInput} name="num1" value={input.num1} type="text"></input>
            <input onChange={handleInput} name="num2" value={input.num2} type="text"></input>
            <button>+</button>
            <span>resultado</span>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería de resolver el problema. Simplemente debes agregar el `onClick` para poder manejar cuando se haga click sobre el botón.

Ten en cuenta que lo que obtienes de los inputs es texto, por lo cual deberás transformarlo a

```javascript
import React from 'react';

export default function Suma() {
  //hook defined
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState({
    num1: "",
    num2: ""
  });
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState();

  //handle input change

  const handleInput = function (e) {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  //suma function

  const suma = function () {
    setResult((+input.num1) + (+input.num2));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={handleInput}
        name="num1"
        value={input.num1}
        type="text"
      ></input>
      <input
        onChange={handleInput}
        name="num2"
        value={input.num2}
        type="text"
      ></input>
      <button onClick={suma}>+</button>
      <span>{result}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Aprovecho a dejarte un [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-frost-5fpox?file=/src/Suma.js:0-811) al sandbox donde lo probe.

Cualquier otra duda, a la orden

Comment: Gracias ! Perdon la ignorancia pero que significa el + adelante de la variable ??

Comment: Lo que hace es transformar la variable a númerica. Te dejo un [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores#operadores_unarios)